# How can I exit a ruby program on strg-c if a SystemExit exception is being catched

Tags: ruby, exception

The code which I can not interrupt by using strg-c (Ctrl-C) :

```
orig_std_out = STDOUT.clone
orig_std_err = STDERR.clone
STDOUT.reopen('/dev/null', 'w')
STDERR.reopen('/dev/null', 'w')

name = cookbook_name(File.join(path, 'Metadata.rb'))
error = 0

begin
  ::Chef::Knife.run(['cookbook', 'site', 'show', "#{name}"])
rescue SystemExit
  error = 1
end
.
.
.
```

In my understanding this behaviour would be reasonable if I would rescue `Exception`, but in this case I am basically catching siblings which only share their parent exception `Exception`.

I have already tried to rescue the exception `Interrupt` and `SignalException` explicitly.

EDIT1: In the hope of clarifying my question I added the following code which i tried:

```
begin
  ::Chef::Knife.run(['cookbook', 'site', 'show', "#{name}"])
rescue SystemExit => e
  msg1 = e.message
  error = 1
rescue Interrupt
  msg2 = "interrupted"
end
```

In both cases - `SystemExit` thrown by `Knife.run` and thrown by Ctrl-C - e.message returns "exit". This does not only mean, that Ctrl-C throws a SystemExit whereas I am expecting it to throw an Interrupt, but also that the error message is the same.
I guess that I have got a major misunderstanding in how ruby works there, since I am not very familiar with ruby.

EDIT2: Further testing revealed that some Ctrl-C interrupts are rescued by `rescue Interrupt`. Is it possible that the command `::Chef::Knife.run(['cookbook', 'site', 'show', "#{name}"])`, which takes about 3-5 seconds to run, creates some kind of subprocess which responds to a Ctrl-C, but always closes with a `SystemExit` and that `rescue Interrupt`only works when it is interrupted just the moment this subprocess is not running? If this is the case, how am I going to be able to Interrupt the whole program?

EDIT3: I initially wanted to attach all the methods which get called on calling Knife.run, however, this would have been too many LoC, although I think my guess that a subcommand is executed was right. The chef gem code can be found [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/tree/master/lib/chef). Thus, the following excerpt is only the part which is the problematic one in my opinion:

```
 rescue Exception => e
  raise if raise_exception || Chef::Config[:verbosity] == 2
  humanize_exception(e)
  exit 100
end
```

Which leads to the question: How can I catch a Ctrl-C which is already rescued by a subcommand?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You noticed that `rescue SystemExit` prevents STRG + C from exiting Ruby and now you are looking for a workaround? Why do you need the `rescue SystemExit`  in the first place?

Comment: On my Mac, with a `gets` statement to make the program wait, Ctrl-C generates an `Interrupt`, if rescued, or an `Exception`, if rescued, else displays `in 'gets': Interrupt`.

Comment: On my Linux system Crtl-C also generates an `Interrupt` and is thus catched by both `Exception` and `Interrupt`, because `Interrupt` inherits from `Exception`. However rescuing `SystemExit` should not catch the Ctrl-C in my understanding.
@spickermann I need to catch `SystemExit`, because `::Chef::Knife.run` exits with `SystemExit` on error.

Comment: Did you consider to `rescue SystemExit => e` and re-raise the exception depending on the `e.message`?

Comment: It is still not clear why you don't write both a `rescue SystemExit` for Chef::Knife and a `rescue Interrupt` for Ctrl-C ?

Comment: @spickermann I have added some code for clarification (hopefully).

Comment: @BernardK I have added some code for clarification (hopefully).

Comment: I made a simulation (`run` containing a `gets`, where I press Ctrl-C) with the `rescue` from EDIT3. If the condition after `raise` is true, `raise` re-raises `Interrupt`. If it is false, the `exit 100` raises `SystemExit`. So why your question _how am I going to be able to Interrupt the whole program?_ in EDIT2 ? Does Ctrl-C not work all the time ? It would mean that this interrupt is disabled by another piece of code. Despite of all your explanations, what is the problem in one sentence ?

Comment: @BernardK first of all, the first condition after `raise` is always false and the second one in my case too, thus it does not re-reraise `Interrupt`, but only a `SystemExit`.
The problem in one sentence is: Interrupts are not treated as such, if ruby is currently executing `::Chef::Knife.run(['cookbook', 'site', 'show', "#{name}"])`

Comment: @BernardK This means that while `Knife.run` is running, an interrupt only results in a `SystemExit` which after all does not result in my program being interrupted, because I rescue `SystemExit` exceptions in case `Knife.run` exits on error with a non-interrupt `SystemExit`.

Comment: I see. All interrupts, including Ctrl-C, are captured by `rescue Exception`, which ends up with `exit 100`, which raises a SystemExit, which you capture, but don't know then it was caused by Ctrl-C. So we need to short-circuit `exit 100`. If you can modify the source, adding `raise if e.class == Interrupt`, for example just after `rescue Exception => e`, would solve your dilemma. That is to say modify `chef-master` -> `lib` -> `chef` -> `knife.rb` after line 444. Can you do this ?

Comment: I have found the source of the gem [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/).

Comment: @BernardK I actually never thought about modifying the chef gem code, but it is actually the cleanest solution. I could do it which means that I would ship my code with the modified chef gem code included. The working alternative is the one mentioned in my answer, however it is not nearly that nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done `gem install chef`. Now I try another solution, replacing only `run_with_pretty_exceptions`, but don't know which `require` to put in the script. I did this :

```
require 'chef'
$:.unshift('Users/b/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/chef-13-6-4/lib')
require 'chef/knife'
```

But then :

```
$ ruby chef_knife.rb 
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
ERROR: Error connecting to https://supermarket.chef.io/api/v1/cookbooks/xyz, retry 1/5
...
```

So, without the whole infrastructure, I can't test the following solution. The idea is that in Ruby you can reopen an existing class and replace a method defined elsewhere. I have to leave you check it :

```
# necessary require of chef and knife ...

class Chef::Knife # reopen the Knife class and replace this method
    def run_with_pretty_exceptions(raise_exception = false)
      unless respond_to?(:run)
        ui.error "You need to add a #run method to your knife command before you can use it"
      end
      enforce_path_sanity
      maybe_setup_fips
      Chef::LocalMode.with_server_connectivity do
        run
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      raise if e.class == Interrupt # <---------- added ********************
      raise if raise_exception || Chef::Config[:verbosity] == 2
      humanize_exception(e)
      exit 100
    end
end

name = cookbook_name(File.join(path, 'Metadata.rb'))
error = 0

begin
  ::Chef::Knife.run(['cookbook', 'site', 'show', "#{name}"])
rescue SystemExit => e
  puts "in rescue SystemExit e=#{e.inspect}"
  error = 1
rescue Interrupt
  puts 'in rescue Interrupt'
end
```

`raise if e.class == Interrupt` will re-raise `Interrupt` if it is one.

Normally I run `ruby -w` to display diagnostics, which would be like this :

```
$ ruby -w ck.rb 
ck.rb:9: warning: method redefined; discarding old run_with_pretty_exceptions
ck.rb:4: warning: previous definition of run_with_pretty_exceptions was here
```

Unfortunately there are so many uninitialized variables and circular require warnings in this gem that this option produces un unmanageable output.

The drawback of this solution is that you have to keep a documentation track of this change, and in case of Chef's release change, somebody has to verify if the code of `run_with_pretty_exceptions` has changed.

Please give me a feedback.

---

**=====  UPDATE  =====**

There is a less intrusive solution, which consists in defining an `exit` method in `Chef::Knife`.

When you see `exit 100`, i.e. a message without receiver, the implicit receiver is `self`, it is equivalent to `self.exit 100`. In our case, `self` is the object created by `instance = subcommand_class.new(args)`, and which is the receiver in `instance.run_with_pretty_exceptions`.

When a message is sent to an object, the message search mechanism starts looking in the class of this object. If there is no method with this name in the class, the search mechanism looks in included modules, then the superclass, etc until it reaches Object, the default superclass of `Chef::Knife`. Here it finds `Object#exit` and executes it.

After defining an `exit` method in `Chef::Knife`, the message search mechanism, when it encounters `exit 100` with an instance of `Chef::Knife` as implicit receiver, will first find this local method and execute it. By previously aliasing the original `Object#exit`, it is still possible to call the original Ruby method which initiates the termination of the Ruby script. This way the local `exit` method can decide either to call the original `Object#exit` or take other action.

Following is a complete example which demonstrates how it works.

```
# ***** Emulation of the gem *****

class Chef end

class Chef::Knife
    def self.run(x)
        puts 'in original run'
        self.new.run_with_pretty_exceptions
    end

    def run_with_pretty_exceptions
        print 'Press Ctrl_C > '
        gets
        rescue Exception => e
            puts
            puts "in run_with_pretty...'s Exception e=#{e.inspect} #{e.class}"
            raise if false # if raise_exception || Chef::Config[:verbosity] == 2
#            humanize_exception(e)
            puts "now $!=#{$!.inspect}"
            puts "about to exit,                     self=#{self}"
            exit 100
    end
end

# ***** End of gem emulation *****

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# ***** This is what you put into your script. *****

class Chef::Knife # reopen the Knife class and define one's own exit
    alias_method :object_exit, :exit

    def exit(p)
        puts "in my own exit with parameter #{p}, self=#{self}"
        puts "$!=#{$!.inspect}"

        if Interrupt === $!
            puts 'then about to raise Interrupt'
            raise # re-raise Interrupt
        else
            puts 'else about to call Object#exit'
            object_exit(p)
        end
    end
end

begin
  ::Chef::Knife.run([])
rescue SystemExit => e
  puts "in script's rescue SystemExit e=#{e.inspect}"
rescue Interrupt
  puts "in script's rescue Interrupt"
end
```

**Execution**. First test with Ctrl-C :

```
$ ruby -w simul_chef.rb 
in original run
Press Ctrl_C > ^C
in run_with_pretty...'s Exception e=Interrupt Interrupt
now $!=Interrupt
about to exit,                     self=#<Chef::Knife:0x007fb2361c7038>
in my own exit with parameter 100, self=#<Chef::Knife:0x007fb2361c7038>
$!=Interrupt
then about to raise Interrupt
in script's rescue Interrupt
```

Second test with a hard interrupt.

In one terminal window :

```
$ ruby -w simul_chef.rb 
in original run
Press Ctrl_C >
```

In another terminal window :

```
$ ps -ef
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0     1     0   0 Fri01PM ??         0:52.65 /sbin/launchd
...
    0   363   282   0 Fri01PM ttys000    0:00.02 login -pfl b /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash
  501   364   363   0 Fri01PM ttys000    0:00.95 -bash
  501  3175   364   0  9:51PM ttys000    0:00.06 ruby -w simul_chef.rb
...
$ kill 3175
```

Back in the first terminal :

```
in run_with_pretty...'s Exception e=#<SignalException: SIGTERM> SignalException
now $!=#<SignalException: SIGTERM>
about to exit,                     self=#<Chef::Knife:0x007fc5a79d70a0>
in my own exit with parameter 100, self=#<Chef::Knife:0x007fc5a79d70a0>
$!=#<SignalException: SIGTERM>
else about to call Object#exit
in script's rescue SystemExit e=#<SystemExit: exit>
```

Considering the code you originally posted, all you have to do is inserting at the beginning, but after the necessary `require` :

```
class Chef::Knife # reopen the Knife class and define one's own exit
    alias_method :object_exit, :exit

    def exit(p)
        if Interrupt === $!
            raise # re-raise Interrupt
        else
            object_exit(p)
        end
    end
end
```

So there is no need to touch the original gem.

Comment: I did not think of overriding that specific method, but that looks like a neat solution. I will definitely test that tomorrow! Is overriding a method out of a gem this way generally considered as clean coding?  Regarding the missing config: you can create a knife.rb using the `knife configure` subcommand which you probably do not want to to.

Comment: @BigX The design of the `Knife` class and your wish to intercept Ctrl-C forces you to touch something. The inconvenient of redefining a gem's method is to have a discrepancy in the long term after an update. But good news, I have found a better solution consisting of defining `exit` in `Knife`, which should be quite harmless. See UPDATE.

Comment: To give feedback to you and others as well: As a matter of fact I am writing rules for (the gem) Foodcritic which means I am basically "in" Foodcritic (hierarchy-wise). For me, the first solution did not work, as it always instantly exited the `Knife.run`. The approach overriding the `exit` method, however, works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thereby I want to add that I had to use `class ::Chef::Knife` as I am inside the gem Foodcritic (which you could not know) and that it did not work being in a (rule) block. Thus I moved it to my library file (basically at the beginning of the code after the requires, as stated by you) and it works perfectly. Not touching the gem here is a big plus for my part, since I do not expect too much active development on my code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows how I am able to interrupt after all:

```
interrupted = false
trap("INT") { interrupted = true} #sent INT to force exit in Knife.run and then exit

begin
  ::Chef::Knife.run(['cookbook', 'site', 'show', "#{name}"]) #exits on error and on interrupt with 100
  if interrupted
    exit
  end
rescue SystemExit => e
  if interrupted
    exit
  end
  error = 1
end
```

The drawback still is, that I am not exactly able to interrupt the `Knife.run`, but only able to trap the interrupt and check after that command whether an interrupt was triggered. I found no way to trap the interrupt and "reraise" it at the same time, so that I am at least able to force an `exit` out of `Knife.run` which I can then exit manually.